# Your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded. How do you allow in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I logged into the Windows Server 2008 as the Administrator.
Trying to download a file from an external Web site.
Get the message "Your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded."
What should I do to allow?
Thanks.

Comment: In almost all cases, web browsing on a server is a bad idea. You should be downloading the files on a workstation, scanning then, and then mapping a drive on the server as administrator and transferring them there. This way, there is much less chance of compromise.

Comment: This server is for my personal Web site, so I am not overly concerned about security.  Good tip regardless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the server the download is coming from to your trusted sites.  Most often, I already have http://microsoft.com in the trusted list and just need to add http://download.microsoft.com as well.

Double click here:

[image]

Click here:

[image]

Type in the base URL of the site:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also apply the default IE Enhanced Security Configuration to certain users and not to others.  This can be done by opening Server Manager and clicking "Configure IE ESC" under "Security Information"...although I hasten to add that MarkM is correct.  If it's a production server, it's a bad idea to use it to browse websites.